# I have a business card template that uses labels and I want to add a watermark/background

Tags: labels, backgrounds, watermark, cards

I am making business cards that use labels to slice them up and give me multiple per page, but I also would like to have a background or watermark on them.

I have tried using this code, but it puts the image in the middle of the page instead of on the individual labels. Is there a better way? Below the following code is the document area for my cards.

Is it possible or is there a better way?

```
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{
    \put(0,0){
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            \vfill
            \centering
            {\transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{background.png}}%
            \vfill
        }
    }
}
```

Code for my actual cards.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,oneside,landscape]{memoir}


%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\usepackage[nolinks]{qrcode}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}





\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro Light}
\LabelCols=5%
\LabelRows=2%
\LeftPageMargin=13.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=8.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=16.5mm%
\BottomPageMargin=16.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=1.5mm%
\InterLabelRow=5.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=6mm%
\RightLabelBorder=6mm%
\TopLabelBorder=7mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=6mm%
\numberoflabels=10%
\LabelGridtrue%  <-- or \LabelGridfalse


%%% DEFINE USER DATA
\newcommand{\Surname}{
daash
}%
\newcommand{\Firstname}{
rad
}%
\newcommand{\Name}{
{\textbf{\Firstname \Surname}} 
}% No size here so it's easier to try out multiple sizes
\newcommand{\Description}{
{Computer Hardware Engineer}
}% No size here so it's easier to try out multiple sizes
\newcommand{\Email}{
rad@gmail.com
}%
\newcommand{\Phone}{
+15
}%
\newcommand{\Website}{
https://github.com/rad-
}%
%Resume address goes here.
\newcommand{\resumedoc}{
https://www.google.com/
}
\newcommand{\Occupation}{
}
%MeCard command to include in QR Code
\newcommand{\MeCard}{
MECARD:N:\Firstname,\Surname;TEL:\Phone;EMAIL:\Email;URL:\Website;;
}
%Content of the QR Code
\newcommand{\TheQRContent}{
\MeCard
}
%Make actual QR code
\newcommand{\MyQRC}{
\qrcode[nolinks, height=2.5cm]{\TheQRContent}
}
%Github QR ocode here
\newcommand{\GitQR}{
\qrcode[nolinks, height=2.5cm]{\Website}
}
%Resume QR code here
\newcommand{\Resume}{
\qrcode[nolinks, height=2.5cm]{\resumedoc}
}
%
\begin{document}
\addresslabel[\fboxsep=5mm]{%
    {%
    \raggedright%
    {\Large\scshape \Name}\\[1ex]

    \small\textit{\Description}\      \vspace{4ex}

    {\textsc{Student, Coder\\ System Architect}}\\   

    \vspace{4ex}%

    \hrule%

    %______________________%

    \vspace{2ex}%
    \begin{center}
        {\small\textit{Phone Number : \Phone}}\\%
        {\small\textit{Email : \Email}}\\%

        \vspace{2ex}%

        {\small\textit{My contact information}
                        \MyQRC}
    \end{center}
    \
    }%
}


\newpage


\addresslabel[\fboxsep=5mm]{%
    {%
    \begin{center}

        {\raggedleft\small\textit{My Resume}}
                        \Resume
        \vspace{2ex}
        \hrule%
        \vspace{2ex}

        %______________________%

        {\small\textit{My Github}\\
                        \GitQR}
    \end{center}

    }%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code so that it will compile!

Comment: Definitely a better way.  Hard to suggest it, though, when you've only given us an incomplete example to work with....

Comment: Apologies, updated the question with full .tex file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rad,

I'm doing the same thing for my cards. I just put the \includgraphics command inside the second "\addresslabel[\fboxsep=5mm]{%" command (the one for the backside of the card) and that should do the trick.